# How to I reference to an external module for terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-aws-modules

In terraform, we can use `Generic Git Repository` to reference to an external source.

```
module "log_group" {
  source  = "git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudwatch?ref=v3.0.0"
```

How do I do it for log group

```
module "log_group" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/cloudwatch/aws//modules/log-group"
  version = "~> 3.0"

  name              = "my-app"
  retention_in_days = 120
}
```

i tried with `git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudwatch/modules/log_group?ref=v3.0.0` but it is incorrect.

Comment: The second one does not work? What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

i found the issue.

i should be using `//` instead of a `/`

```
module "log_group" {
  source = "git::https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-cloudwatch//modules/log-group?ref=v3.0.0"
```